# Getting 404s when calling Actions in MVC3 with jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

In my MVC3 app, I'm using $.ajax to call a method of type JsonResult to get data to be displayed:

```
 function GetData(e) {
    var ordersId = e.row.cells[0].innerHTML; //this is fine
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/Documents/GetDocumentData",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: "{'id': '"+ordersId +"'}",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (result) {
        //load window
         },
         error: function (result) {
            if (!result.success)
        //show error
         }
     });
```

This is my Action:

```
   [HttpPost] 
        public JsonResult GetDocumentData(string id)
    {
           //my code
           return Json(new { success = true});

        }
```

When im debugging on my development machine, it works fine. I deployed it to my test web server and i get '404 page not found dev/testwebsite/Documents/GetDocumentData' I should get this when debugging if something was wrong, but i dont. Why am I getting this error? Thanks

Comment: What's the url from that you're access to the `Action`

Comment: I dont understand your question....

Comment: Why's the url that shows in the view when you're testing the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL in the javascript is wrong, if that dev/testwebsite/Documents/GetDocumentData is the URL on the server.

You should be using @Url.Action() to automatically form those URLs in the cshtml page.

Example:

```
@Url.Action("actionName","controllerName"  )
```

So, for your specific case, it would be:

```
@Url.Action( "GetDocumentData", "Documents" )
```

In the javascript, it would look like this:

```
function GetData(e) {
    var ordersId = e.row.cells[0].innerHTML; //this is fine
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDocumentData","Documents")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{'id': '"+ordersId +"'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
        //load window
    },
    error: function (result) {
        if (!result.success)
        //show error
    }
});
```

Comment: You mean like this:              url: @Html.ActionUrl("/Documents/GetDocumentData"). In my $.ajax call?

Comment: That's not what you posted...  And the URL in what you posted is inconsistent with the URL in the javascript.

Comment: How do i use Html.ActionUrl is my question?

Comment: Is that in the CSHTML file or in a separate .js file?

Comment: Ok.  Then Visual Studio should show you several overloads of the function.  But, in general, you call it like the example that will be in the answer momentarily.

Comment: Now im getting a 500 meaning it at least made it to the server. So im guess im good. Thanks