# Ajax with custom Form Authentication in MVC3 project

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, form-authentication

I have an MVC3 project with custom form authentication.
I got the authentication to work fine (I used the "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" property in order to make sure it worked)

I use on my of my forms an Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/MyPages/MyControllerFunction',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (result) { $('#MyJavaTemplate').tmpl(result).appendTo('#MyHtmlTable'); },
        error: function (result) {
            $('#errorDisplay').html(result.responseText);
        }
    })
});
```

When I get to this page (and the ajax should call this controller's function) I get this error:

**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

My controller function:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyControllerFunction()
    {
        var MyEntity = MyBusinessLogic.GetByID(1);
        return Json(MyEntity);
    }
```

(I also tried to add the [Authorized] attribute and it didn't help)

It only happens to me with mhen I call the controller's function through ajax. Before I changed my program to work with form authentication, It all worked. It's as if the user is not authenticated (even though it is)

What should solve this problem?

Comment: can you show your controller please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you have a GET specified on that controller action, where is should be a POST

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult MyControllerFunction()
```

Comment: I have an HTTPPOST attribute on the function, and before I added the form authentication I checked it and it worked perfectly...

My Function:
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetOneDoc()
        {
            //DO STUFF...
           
            return Json(MyObject);
        }

Comment: is url ajax url url: '/MyPages/GetOneDoc', ?  what is your controller called?  looks like it might be a routing issue.  what is the url when you don't use ajax?

Comment: Sorry, You're right, I corrected my question - My controller name is MyPagesController and the function name is MyControllerFunction.

Once again I'll say - this function with this ajax call worked perfectly good when I used the default authentication method (Windows). The problem appeared as I changed to Form Authentication

Comment: got you, will think about that in meantime shouldn't you have JsonResult instead of ActionResult?

Comment: I saw a tutorial in which it worked well just this way. Also, I can't see why this thing will work as it is when it uses windows authentication and won't work when using form authentication....

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION !

It was here:
[Getting 404s when calling Actions in MVC3 with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164584/getting-404s-when-calling-actions-in-mvc3-with-jquery)

All I had to do is change the:

```
url: '/MyPages/MyControllerFunction'
```

to
url: '@Url.Action("MyControllerFunction","MyPages")'